# How to recover destroyed laravel project with composer

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, composer-php, alerts

I am using laravel 4.2.
Today I had to reinstall one of my plugins, and now all my project has been destroyed.
here's my composer.json file :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.8",
                "mews/captcha": "dev-master",
                "prologue/alerts": "dev-master",
        "yangqi/htmldom": "dev-master",
        "scalia/sphinxsearch": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libraries",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

All i wanted to do was changing mews/captcha plugin with something else.
After implementation of my new captcha plugin, i tried to update project with composer using "composer update".
Then i realized prologue/alerts are not supporting laravel 4.2 anymore, according to the github and composer errors.

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Installation request for prologue/alerts dev-master -> satisfiable by prologue/alerts[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - prologue/alerts dev-master requires illuminate/session ~5 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.x-dev], illuminate/session[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.2.0-BETA1, 5.0.x-dev].
    - don't install illuminate/session 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.2.x-dev, v4.2.0, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

I can't remove prologue/alerts plugin. All i want is to recover my project, i have the old commits / backup files. But composer doesn't let me to.

Also, tried to remove prologue/alerts from composer.json, and the other properties from app.php, but composer still doesn't help me.
 **The error is "Class 'Prologue\Alerts\AlertsServiceProvider' not found"**, which means composer tried to install the newer version of prologue/alerts ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general problem is that you are using branches instead of versions. branches have two major problems:

1. They don't point to a distinct code that was committed once in time, but are a moving target that constantly gets updates.
2. They inherently are of development stability, which could be an acceptable risk when used as top level dependency in the project, but will create problems if used inside a package that has to be included somewhere else.

The answer of @milz is pointing into the correct direction, but you should go the whole way: For every package you use, replace every reference to a branch with a release version or a version range.

[mews/captcha](https://packagist.org/packages/mews/captcha) - released versions 1.0.1, 2.0.0 and 2.0.1 - only 1.0.1 is compatible with Laravel 4. You might want to use `1.0.*` to catch bug fixes, even though it's unlikely they will happen.

[prologue/alerts](https://packagist.org/packages/prologue/alerts) - release versions 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.2.0, 0.3.0 and 0.4.0. Versions 0.1 and 0.2 require Laravel 4.0, 0.3.0 allows ANY 4.x, and 0.4.0 jumped to any Laravel 5.0 version. Pick `0.3.*`.

[yangqi/htmldom](https://packagist.org/packages/yangqi/htmldom) - no released versions. As hard as it is: You should avoid using this package as long as the maintainers don't tag a release version. It doesn't correctly state it's dependencies as well - it has a dependency on Laravel for the service provider. Ask the maintainers to tag a release, or switch to a different package. This package is likely to repeat the misery you are experiencing now.

[scalia/sphinxsearch](https://packagist.org/packages/scalia/sphinxsearch) - Versions 0.1, 0.1.1 and 0.2 are all compatible with Laravel 4 - pick `0.2.*`.

Note that for all versions you might also think about not only accepting bugfixes, but also compatible updates. This would change the version requirement from `x.y.*` to `~x.y`. I'd recommend this.

Also note that depending on which version of the master branch you were using, by switching to a tagged release you might go back some commits. This might revert bug fixes that were committed to master, but never tagged as a release. If you find out that a package you are using has unreleased bugfixes, you should also ask the maintainers to release these bug fixes.

Depending on their speed of reaction and resolution of your request, you might make a decision of continue using that package, or switch to something else.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are useful actually.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can take a look at the list of [prologuephp/alerts releases](https://github.com/prologuephp/alerts/releases). If you take a look at the `composer.json` from *v0.3.0* to *0.4.0-beta.1* you'll see the dependencies changing from:

```
"illuminate/config": "~4",
"illuminate/session": "~4",
"illuminate/support": "~4",
```

To:

```
"illuminate/config": "~5",
"illuminate/session": "~5",
"illuminate/support": "~5"
```

So, if your project is using Laravel 4, you just need to use the correct release. In your `composer.json`, instead of `"prologue/alerts": "dev-master",` use **`"prologue/alerts": "0.3.0"`**.

Comment: I will be checking it out and feedback the results. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i did so far :

1. Removed "prologue/alerts": "dev-master", from composer.json file,
2. in app/config/app.php, removed 
   'Prologue\Alerts\AlertsServiceProvider', from providers and 
   'Alert' => 'Prologue\Alerts\Facades\Alert', from aliases
3. "composer update" from console.

This might not be the great solution but i managed to recover my project without non-supported plugins.